# How to Update application instead of Replace application in Android for Non-Market Application

Tags: android, background, notifications, updates

Thanks in advance for reading the query.

I am trying to update my application from lower version to higher version. As my application is not on market, so I want to update from my web service.

What I want ?

I want to update my application silently in background without user intervetion. If this is not possible, update application with minimal user intervenstion (just like Google Play update) with notification of update application and not as replace application.

What did I did ?

I tried to update my application by

old application Android Manifest

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

New application Android Manifest

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1"
```

Code for install new update

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse(packageName.toString());
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, packageURI);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/"  + ApkName.toString())),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

What I get ?

1. I am not able to update application silently in background.
2. I get Replace application instead of Update application, while installing update.

Thanks & Regards
Krishna V. Mahadik

Answer (score 1):

ok use can use GCM service to notify the user for update

here is link http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

and whenever you update the application, its install the new version keeping the 
   application seting  as it is. This thing i have checked

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.
I am working on the same following http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/434338/Android-GCM-Push-Notification 
link

Comment: But, how the apk is updating?? can anyone please tell about it?